# Wildcards not resolving subdirectories in DispatcherServlet

Tags: java, spring, apache

I am trying to create a restcontroller that has a couple rules for mapping URIs with path variables. With my current configuration it seems like it will match my url-pattern exactly, but if I add any kind of subdirectory it will not get mapped. See my configuration

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SpringMVC</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/proxy/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/proxy")
public class ProxyController {

    @RequestMapping("")
    @ResponseBody
    public String test(HttpServletRequest request) throws URISyntaxException{
        LOG.info("base");
        return "done";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/testplace")
    @ResponseBody
    public String test2(HttpServletRequest request) throws URISyntaxException{
        LOG.info("base");
        return "done2";
    }
```

So hitting localhost:8080/app/proxy returns correctly, but localhost:8080/app/proxy/testplace gives me

> "No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/app/proxy/testplace] in DispatcherServlet with name 'SpringMVC'"

even though in startup I can see

> "Mapped "{[/proxy/testplace/]}" onto public java.lang.String ProxyController(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest) throws java.net.URISyntaxException"

Is there a setting or some other configuration option I'm missing here?

Thanks

Comment: why are you throwing `URISyntaxException`

Comment: I stripped the methods down for debugging purposes